# How to concatenate paths in msys

Tags: msys2

In a bash shell script I have to set PYTHONPATH. We have the following code:

```
if [ ${OS} == Windows_NT ]; then
    PYTHONPATH="${TEST_DIR}input;${TEST_DIR}"
else
    PYTHONPATH="${TEST_DIR}input:${TEST_DIR}"
fi
export PYTHONPATH
```

This also works under msys2 as long as TEST_DIR is an absolute path. However, in my code TEST_DIR can be both an absolute and a relative path. When for example TEST_DIR=. msys2 does not perform a magic : to ; conversion, and as a result PYTHONPATH is not correctly set.

*Underlying details*

When msys2 exports a environment variable like
 `/c/first/path:/usr/local` it transfroms that to external non-msys program to an Windows environment variable such as `c:/first/path;c:/msys2/usr/local`. In that process it converts the unix style file names to Windows style file names, and transforms the `:` to a `;` -- which is needed as a `:` is a common part of a Windows file name. However, this seems not to happen when msys2 does not recognize the environment variable as a path, as seems the case with `./:./input`.

Comment: David, added the Underlying details section as answer to your question.

Comment: Hey, thanks for clarifiying.  I am unable to reproduce your problem in my installation of MSYS2.  Here is a shell session from my MINGW32 shell showing what I tried:  https://gist.github.com/DavidEGrayson/e87cb1631ab113ed1c9a86eb97a9ab2e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by David Grayson the code as used under Linux also works under MSYS2 and there is no need to ever use a `;` as a path separator. So the correct code to use both under Windows and linux is:

```
PYTHONPATH="${TEST_DIR}input:${TEST_DIR}"
export PYTHONPATH
```

Answer (score 0):

A work around so far is to use code like:

```
case ${TEST_DIR} in
 /*)
   sep=":"
 ;;
 *)
   if [ ${OS} == Windows_NT ]; then
      sep=";" # on windows when TEST_DIR is an relative path we shall concatenate paths in an environment variable with a ;
   else
      sep=":"
   fi
esac
PYTHONPATH="${TEST_DIR}input${sep}${TEST_DIR}"
export PYTHONPATH
```

However, this looks clumsy and I am not convinced all possible paths are correctly handled.